# ActiveReports behaving differently on server

Tags: activereports

I have an activereports report which when I run on my localhost, the document is fine.  However when I run the report on the server, the items are not displayed in the right location.  The left and right margins look the same on both versions.

However the spacing between the items up and down are different on the server version.  The spacing needs to be exact because the report is being printed on "printed" sheets.

When I examine the output, one page is (localhost) 9.24x11.69 and the other is (server) 9.24x11.00 .  Is ActiveReports affected by any windows settings?

I use the same .rpx on both servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that for that report, we hadn't blanked out the printer name and once we'd done that, it was working again.

printer.printername=""